# Pandas read dataframe from csv with index as string, not int

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My csv file is as following :

```
INDEX, VAL
04016170,22
04206261,11
0420677,11
```

`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='INDEX')`

How can I force pandas to read the index as string and not as integer (to preserve the first `0`) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass the [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) as a param this will map the column to the passed dtype:

```
In [130]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""INDEX,VAL
04016170,22
04206261,11
0420677,11"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col='VAL', dtype={'INDEX':str})
df

Out[130]:
        INDEX
VAL          
22   04016170
11   04206261
11    0420677

In [131]:    
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 22 to 11
Data columns (total 1 columns):
INDEX    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

**EDIT**

OK, you can do it this way, there is a bug here when you explicitly set the `index_col` in `read_csv`, so you have to load the csv in first and then call `set_index` after loading:

```
In [134]:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype={'INDEX':str})
df = df.set_index('INDEX')
df

Out[134]:
          VAL
INDEX        
04016170   22
04206261   11
0420677    11
```

Comment: I'm sorry i made a mistake : index_col is INDEX (not VAL), I made the correction asap but you where too fast ! I want INDEX col as the INDEX, and keep the leading 0 in the index

Answer (score 4):

Another solution in two lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col=0)
df.index = [str(x) for x in df.index]
```

or

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
```